# How to update static variable by passing the parameters of the same variable and nonstatic ones into static function in java?

Tags: java

```java
package staticassignment3;
    
public class Booking {
    
    private String customerEmail;
    private int seatsRequired;
    private static int seatsAvailable;
    private boolean isBooked;
        
    static {
        seatsAvailable = 400;
    }
    public Booking(String customerEmail,  int seatsRequired) {
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
        this.seatsRequired = seatsRequired;
    }
        
    
    public String getCustomerEmail() {
        return this.customerEmail;
    }
    public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail) {
        this.customerEmail= customerEmail;
    }
        
    public int getSeatsRequired() {
        return this.seatsRequired;
    }
    public void setSeatsRequired(int seatsRequired) {
        this.seatsRequired = seatsRequired;
    }
        
    public static int getSeatsAvailable() {
        return Booking.seatsAvailable;
    }
    public static void setSeatsAvailable(int seatsAvailable) {
        Booking.seatsAvailable = Booking.seatsAvailable - this.seatsRequired;
    }
        
    public boolean isBooked() {
        if(Booking.seatsAvailable>= this.seatsRequired) {
            Booking.setSeatsAvailable(seatsAvailable);
            this.isBooked = true;
        }
        else {
            this.isBooked = false;
        }
        return isBooked;
    }
}
```

In the above Booking class, I want to update the static variable `seatsAvailable` by using the static method `setSeatsAvailable` but I am passing a nonstatic variable in it i.e `this.seatsRequired` which is not permitted. Is there any alternative to update the `seatsAvailable` without changing the code so much?

```java
package staticassignment3;
    
public class Tester {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Booking booking1 = new Booking("jack@email.com", 100);
        Booking booking2 = new Booking("jill@email.com", 350);
    
                
        Booking[] bookings = { booking1, booking2 };
                      
        for (Booking booking : bookings) {
            if (booking.isBooked()) {
                System.out.println(booking.getSeatsRequired()+" seats successfully booked for "+booking.getCustomerEmail());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry "+booking.getCustomerEmail()+", required number of seats are not available!");
                System.out.println("Seats available: "+Booking.getSeatsAvailable());
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `seatsAvailable` should not be static, and it should not be a member of `Booking`.  You are missing a `Venue` object, where `seatsAvailable` belongs.  Providing an answer to your question as written would be misleading, since it would imply your design is reasonable, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

> *in above Booking class i want to update seatsAvailable static variable by using setSeatsAvailable static method but i am passing nonstatic varible in it i.e this.seatsRequired which is not permitted.is there any alternate to achive the updated seatsAvailable static varibale without doing major changes in code*

When calling a static method, there is no assocated object instance. So, it is not valid to use `this` inside a static method, since `this` refers to the current object (but you have none).

Specfically, this method isn't correct:

```
public static void setSeatsAvailable(int seatsAvailable) {
    Booking.seatsAvailable = Booking.seatsAvailable - this.seatsRequired;
}
```

If you want to keep the method static, you could pass an additional parameter to the method – an instance of `Booking` – and then replace `this.seatsRequired` with `booking.seatsRequired`, like this:

```
public static void setSeatsAvailable(int seatsAvailable, Booking booking) {
    Booking.seatsAvailable = Booking.seatsAvailable - booking.seatsRequired;
}
```